# read_csv file loads column names as one long string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

When I load a csv file, I receive a "`KeyError`" when setting the index. I see that the column names are not loaded as desired. For example:

```
   cleaned_sql = cleaned_sql.set_index('a')
print(cleaned_sql.columns.tolist())
```

Looks like so (desired):

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

And the code not okay:

```
col_names = pd.read_csv(in_file, nrows=0).columns
print(col_names)
```

Looks like so (NOT desired):

```
Index(['"e","f","g"'])
```

The csv column row:

```
"e","f","g"
```

Do I need to set another attribute in read_csv file? It's here I suspect the problem is. As you see from the print statement the result is wrapped in the list, in single quotes (so all 3 e,f,g are in a string together).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: Why did you mark this down and attach this link?

Comment: have you read the page I linked to ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: yes

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resole this the way I wanted to (directly in read_csv), so here's what I came up with as a cheap workaround:

```
col_names = pd.read_csv(in_file, nrows=0).columns
col_names = col_names[0].split(",")
rev_col_name = []
for i in range(len(col_names)):
    rev_col_name.append(col_names[i].strip('"'))

df = pd.read_csv(in_file, names=rev_col_name, encoding='latin-1', delimiter=",")
```